# JDBC Query on MySQL very slow after altering collation

Tags: mysql, jdbc, collation

I have written a plug-in for a third-party application that runs the plug-in every minute.
My plug-in runs a JDBC query on MySQL and reports the result. I recently changed the collation of the table and all its columns, and after that the queries run very slowly.

I tried reverting the collation configuration but it didn't help. I also removed all the history from the table and inserted fresh data. And then I dropped the database and created a new one. Still I have very slow queries. And the interesting thing is that when I run the query manually through mysql-client, it runs as fast as expected.

This happens for some very simple queries like:
    select 1 as Avail from Report limit 1
but some other queries run pretty fast.

Another thing that I changed before this problem occurred was that I turned off the binary logs of mysql. I really doubt that it has anything to do with the performance, but I think you might need to know it.

This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Well, reroll back changes you made and apply then one by one. And make some test s

Comment: @LHristov I rolled back everything I could think of, but the problem didn't go away!